# PostgreSQL Java Authentication error

Tags: java, postgresql, netbeans

I am trying to connect netbeans with postgreSQL. However, it gives connection error even though my username and password is correct. Following code is my persistence.xml. Can you help me please?

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="travelling" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>com.travelling.entity.CbrCase</class>
    <class>com.travelling.entity.CbrCaseAttraction</class>
    <class>com.travelling.entity.CbrAttractionXCategory</class>
    <class>com.travelling.entity.CbrCategory</class>
    <class>com.travelling.entity.CbrAttraction</class>
    <class>com.travelling.entity.CbrCaseXCategory</class>
    <class>com.travelling.entity.CbrDay</class>
    <class>com.travelling.entity.CbrDayXAttraction</class>
    <class>com.travelling.entity.CbrAttractionXAttraction</class>
    <properties>  
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/travelling"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="*****"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="*****"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

and this is the error:

```
Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

and i am pretty sure my password is correct because i can log in with the same password to the database.

Comment: If Postgres says: "*password authentication failed*" then you can be pretty sure that the password is *not* correct.

Comment: however i can use the same password to login the database from postgre's application and it does not give any error.

Comment: Are you sure you log in to the database running on *your* computer and not some other server?

Comment: yeah i am logging in the database which is on my computer and i am also trying to log in to that database from netbeans.

Comment: Either the password isn't really the same, or you're connecting to a different PostgreSQL instance. Check the port and hostname. Look at the *server error log* of the PostgreSQL server to see if it reports any extra details. If desperate and stuck use `wireshark` to examine client/server communication.

Answer (score 3):

I've been having similar issues, and tried to fix this in my pg_hba.conf file. This is located here:

```
/etc/postgresql/9.5/main
```

I changed the file with the following:

```
host       dbtest    user  127.0.0.1/32 trust
```

The conf file uses the following format:
type,     database,     user,     adress,     method

The trust method allows a connection without username or password(read more [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html)).

This should fix the problem.